# ModuleNotFoundError on installed package in virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, python-import, spotipy

I created a virtual environment in python for my flask project and installed the spotipy package using pip. Under Lib/site-packages I can see the spotipy module. When I try to reinstall the package using python -m pip install spotipy, it says the requirements are already satisfied. This all makes me think the package is installed properly.

When I import spotipy in my app.py file, use it in a function, and try flask run, the terminal returns

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy'

I've looked through the forums and many of the suggestions have been to check that the vscode interpreter matches the python interpreter I am using. I did this and it is correct. The only thing I see that seems to be peculiar is that when I installed spotipy, the terminal showed this:

> Requirement already satisfied: spotipy in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (2.23.0)

While when the module error shows up I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
> **import**(module_name)

I'm not sure if this means that vscode is looking for the spotipy module in a different folder than the one it seems to have been installed in? But the installation and importing of flask seems to be working just fine...I'm new to virtual environments so I'm a little unsure what to try next or what this means.

Comment: Yes, you obviously have a mismatch of Python interpreters. You are not using the same Python interpreter every time. You have installed libraries for one Python interpreter but you run code with another Python interpreter. Nothing we can help you with beyond repeating the same things that you have already read. -- Maybe you need to read again the documentation of your tools, IDEs, and so on to really understand how to configure and use them.

Comment: @sinoroc the problem then is that i'm probably not understanding 'interpreters' correctly. would you be able to explain what you mean by i'm not using the same python interpreter every time? and shouldn't flask fail as well if that's the case? i use jupyter and vscode as my IDE. for this project i'm only using vscode.

Comment: Basically each `python.exe` is a different Python interpreter. If you install Python 3.9 and Python 3.11 you have at least 2 Python interpreters. -- Then every time you create a Python virtual environment, there will be a `Scripts/python.exe` inside the virtual environment's directory, although technically it is not a full stand-alone interpreter it counts as a different Python interpreter isolated from the other ones (including isolated from the Python interpreter used to create the virtual environment). -- Read tutorials and docs, we do not do individual support on StackOverflow.

Comment: @sinoroc ok this breakdown was helpful and i was able to find a solution. when i activated the environment I used Scripts\activate.bat when others recommend using \activate.ps1 instead. this seems to have resolved my issue.

Comment: I do not use Windows (so I also do not use Powershell), but yes I guess you might need the `activate.ps1` if you use Powershell. -- Also, in situations like yours, a foolproof way is: instead of activating the virtual environment, directly use the executables in the virtual environment's `Scripts` directory. For example: `path\to\venv\Scripts\python -m pip install spotipy`.

Comment: @sinoroc ok interesting! i assumed you had to activate the venv in order to use it. I'll have to look into this more i guess